# Good compression algorithm for low entropy image

Tags: image, algorithm, compression

I am currently trying to further compress a very simple image. The image uses 2 sets of colors as well as 1 character per "pixel". each set of color may be 1 of 16 options. Because of this I have already combined both colors into 1 byte per pixel representing both of them. I already implemented MTF and BWT encoding methods to assist in RLE. I am positive I can get some more compression out of it however I am not sure what algorithm to use. I have tried huffman however because of the fact the image tends to be small already and RLE compresses most of it due to the lack of entropy, huffman half the time increases the size by adding its decoding table to the file. Please note this will also be run on a slower system so any really heavy algorithms may not work either.

Comment: Is using a custom-made compression algorithm an option? It seems like a very use-case specific problem.

Comment: That could be an option yes however I do not have the expertise in this to actually create a custom algorithm specifically for this.

Comment: I don't understand "uses 2 sets of colors" -- do you mean each pixel has 2 colours, each being 1 of 16 possibilities?  Or each pixel has a single colour that is either from set #1 or set #2 (so 32 possibilities in total)?  If the latter, you only need 5 bits instead of a full byte.

Comment: each pixel is created from a "background color" and a "character color" the background and character may both be colored separately. The full color table for this image is 16 colors. So the former is correct.

Comment: Just to clarify, low entropy means high compressibility because of the predictable nature of the data, did you mean high entropy (i.e. completely random data)? If so then be aware that it is impossible to get any compression of high entropy (random or near-random) data.

Comment: No the images tend to be very low entropy due to the fact colors dont change too often from pixel to pixel. The reason I know the image can be compressed further is because I know it is low entropy

Comment: What is your achieved ratio compared to plain 7-zip? And if i understand the format, what do you achieve outputting both color planes seperately and using optimized PNG, WebP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it sounds like you should compress the background and character color images separately. Second, you say that "the colors don't change too often from pixel to pixel". Are some colors "closer" to each other than others? I.e., when color changes from color x, is it more likely to change to a small subset of the remaining colors? If so, you can map the colors to be more adjacent to those they are likely to change to, and taking differences before coding. Then runs of the same color become runs of zeros, and changes to the "next" color become ones.

Once you have a good representation as a series of bytes with lots of runs and a skewed probability of occurrence of bytes values, e.g. lots of zeros and one, then apply zlib or gzip to take advantage of the apparent redundancy and skew.

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning for compressing both colors separately? As far as I can tell combining them together promises at least a 50% compression ratio before attempting any major algorithms

Comment: I haven't seen the images, but from the description "background" and "character", they sound uncorrelated. If they are uncorrelated, then the compression will be more effective separately than mixed. As for packing into bytes, that's what zlib is for. A sequence of bytes containing only values of 0..15 will be compressed to about four bits per byte by zlib.

Comment: its not that they are uncorrelated. "character" overlays "background" on each pixel. since each can be 1 of 16 characters. since at most that would be 15 or 1111 in bits then together they can at most be 11111111 or a single byte. Since these both tend to change together combining them saves a bit off my current RLE method. as for zlib unfortunately I am doing this on a platform with no current methods of compression implemented so I have to either implement or reimplement everything myself.

Comment: "Correlated" would mean that the background and character images have features that look like each other in the same locations. E.g. the the red, green, and blue images from a color photograph are correlated, since they each look like shadows of each other.

Comment: What do you mean by "since these both tend to change together"?

Comment: If your platform does not and cannot have zlib (don't you have a C compiler?), and if you "do not have the expertise in this to actually create a custom algorithm", then I'm afraid that you're out of luck.

Comment: The platform is sandboxed within a single language so I would have to program a way for it to understand C within that language. But yes I guess I have this as compressed as I will get it in that case. That being said your suggestion did give me an idea on how to change my RLE method to be more efficient so you were very helpful! I am getting a 70-90% compression so I guess at this point I can't really complain